# extract full path FIND with special character handling

Tags: linux, rsync, find, path

Executing a comand like:

```
find /some_path -mtime -3 -type f -name "*.txt"
```

the out is something like:

```
/some_path/file 1.txt
/some_path/file2.txt
```

If I include this output in rsync with something like:

```
rsync --progress --protect-args --files-from=<(find /source_path -mtime -3 -type f -name "*.txt") /source_path /dest_path
```

The command will make the copy just for `file 2.txt` for the first one the output will be `failed: No such file or directory (2)`

The problem is related of course withe the space in the name, how can i solve it?

I need FIND to use `-mtime -3`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-print0` option in find and the `--from0` option in rsync for the filename with special characters.

For your command it would be `-print0 option in find and the --from0 option in rsync`